# How to extend field in UserCreationForm in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

I have been trying to add a phone number field in UserCreationForm so that on registration a user gives its phone number but unfortunately phone number is not storing. it accepts the Phone number on the registration page but it doesn't show the phone number on the webpage. I think it is not storing.

**forms.py**

```
class myCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
ph= forms.CharField(max_length=400, required=True, label='Phone')
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name' ,'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','ph']

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(myCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.ph = self.cleaned_data["ph"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
form = myCreateForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = myCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('loginPage')
return render(request , 'register.html', {'form' : form})
```

**template**

```
{%for i in user%}
Hi {{i.first_name}}<br>
Username : {{i.username}}<br>
E-Mail : {{i.email}}<br>
Phone : {{i.ph}}<br>
{%endfor%}
```

but on my webpage, it shows everything except phone number.

***Please Help Me Out***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the Django User model.See the 
 [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

For example let's create a new model `Profile` which will have `OneToOne` relation with django user model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50..)
```

Now in your view

```
form = myCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        phone = form.cleaned_data.get('ph')
        Profile.objects.create(user=user,phone=ph)
        return redirect...
```

Now in the template `{{i.profile.phone}}` will give the result for phone field.